# Can SQL Azure scale without any specific technique or administration (partitioning/replication...)?

Tags: scalability, requirements, administration, azure-sql-database

Can SQL Azure scale without any specific technique or administration like Google App Engine's BigTable? No manual partitioning or replication required?

Comment: "Manual partitioning" of the database is all part of your database design. Before tearing apart SQL Azure too much, I must first ask, "How much can SQL Server scale without table partitioning or replication?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean scale to meet increasing demand, or do you mean increase in size to accommodate additional data?

With respect to size: you pick the "edition" of the database (web or business) - both have different size limitations.  You are billed based on size only.  max size is 50gb.  Once edition is picked, the capacity will increase up to max allowed to accommodate your data.  You do nothing special.

With respect to scale to meet performance demands... you are abstracted away from managing really anything that has to do with scalability from SQL Azure perspective... Your database is colocated with other databases on various SQL servers running in MS data center.  theoretically your database will be moved to a less-busy server if it becomes too hot... however, SQL Azure is not considered to be highly scalable solution (ie: facebook/twitter quality).

If you need mega-scalability, you'll need to go with Azure Table Storage

Comment: Thanks. In my point of view, SQL store has definite limit. However the  table store is interesting.

Comment: How many Facebook's or Twitter's are out there? Not too many. The majority of applications will scale just find on SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1):

For the majority of applications, SQL Azure will scale just fine.

"Will it scale?" Now that is the question a lot of us wonder about SQL Azure. Especially since you can't tell it how much Ram, CPU Cores or replicated servers with load balancing to allocate. With Windows Azure you can tell it how many of each resource you want your application hosted on, but that isn't the case with SQL Azure. This may sound really bad to some, but SQL Azure is designed to "automagically" scale the database server to your needs. What that means I honestly can't say, as I haven't (as of yet) found much official information from Microsoft on that topic.

With extremely high traffic sites, such as Facebook and Twitter, it has been suggested that non-relational databases (such as Azure Table Storage) can scale better since the database has less overhead when querying data. If you need relational database features (such as foreign key relationships and sql join functionality) then you probably want to use SQL Azure.

It's not as clear cut as "to SQL Azure, or not to SQL Azure." There are database architecture design patterns that can be used such as denormalizing database tables (require less joins per query) and [Horizontally Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) your data to allow your design to better scale.

A Hybrid or Mixed solution of both SQL Azure and Azure Table Storage can be used too. If you have some data that requires relational queries, then put it in SQL Azure. If you have data that does not require a relational database, then you could put it in Azure Table Storage.

Remember, the database design is part of the overall architecture of your application and you should plan it out just as much as you plan whether to use TDD, IOC and Dependency Injection. After all, if your database can't scale, it doesn't matter how awesome the application code is.

Aside, Thinking about this topic makes me wonder what XBox Live and Bing Search use for their database needs. Is it Relational, Non-Relational or Hybrid?

Comment: I was curious about some kind of abstraction layer which can eliminate of scaling management virtually unlimited...